# Extended time measurement with CPU_TIME() in fortran with loops located after the last call?

Tags: performance, fortran, cpu-time

I am trying to measure the time of a given loop with the `cpu_time` function.
The piece of code I am currently testing is as follows. `t_start` and `t_finish` are two reals.

```
    call cpu_time(t_start)
    
    do ii = 1, 1000000
        
        ** do something that produces an integer named set_count **
        
        ! --- Result is stored in an array of integers named buffer
        buffer(ii) = set_count
    
    end do
    
    call cpu_time(t_finish)

    write(*,'(A,F12.6,A)')'Elapsed CPU time = ',(t_finish-t_start),' seconds.'
   
    !do ii = 0, Ns
    !    sethands(ii) = sethands(ii) + count((buffer == ii))
    !end do
```

When compiled with GNU Fortran 13.2.0 (with the command `gfortran -O3 <file_in> -o <file_out>`), and executed in Mysys Mingw64 environment in Windows 10, the code gives the following console output:

```
Elapsed CPU time =     1.531250 seconds.
```

Now I uncomment the small block which is placed after the last call of the `cpu_time` function. In this loop, `sethands` is an array of integers:

```
    do ii = 0, Ns
        sethands(ii) = sethands(ii) + count((buffer == ii))
    end do
```

The execution time is much longer, and I obtain the following result:

```
Elapsed CPU time =   127.109375 seconds.
```

The result looks very surprising to me. Why do I have a different result? And why such a large discrepancy? If the last loop is time consuming, why is `t_finish-t_start` affected, as it is supposed to be calculated before entering in the last loop?

How to improve the storage of the `buffer` data in the last loop, so as to avoid such a large lead time?

Pardon me if this question is a duplication of a similar thread.

Comment: If the value of `buffer` is never required, why should a compiler waste your time calculating it?

Comment: But it will be better if you can provide details of how you ask the compiler to optimize (such as command-line options) and more detail of the code: see [mre].

Comment: From your first comment, should I understand the ```buffer``` variable is not calculated in the first large loop if not used somewhere else afterwards?

Comment: That's certainly a possibility, and a good guess. We can't be sure from your example here, because there may be side effects which means that the optimization doesn't happen (and something else is causing your observation). Consider the code `x=0; x=0; x=0`: how many assignments of 0 need be done? How many assignments of 0 in `x=0; x=0; x=1`?

Comment: To say anthing more, you have to provide the *exact* code. See [mcve]. The link is for debugging, but applies to your situation as well.

Comment: Compilers are very, very good at data flow analysis, because the fastest way to calculate something is to not calculate it at all if it isn't needed.  If you're trying to benchmark a calculation at a higher optimization level, it's always a good idea to do something to make the compiler think that every result is being used, which can be as simple as using it as a procedure argument (in the absence of ability to inline the procedure).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question, the following code will be likely more efficient:

```
do i = 1, size(buffer)
   ii = buffer(i)
   if (ii >= 0 .and. ii <= Ns) sethands(ii) = sethands(ii) + 1
end do
```

You don't even need the test if you know that it will always evaluate to `.true.`